# Associate data with radio buttons inside of gravity form and dynamically output them in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms to generate conditional responses to users filling out a form.

The user selects the first radio box (first question) and then follows up by checking the second (second question).

Each of the first radio options each have 3 values associated with them.

Depending on the users second answer I need to determine which of the 3 to display in the confirmation message.

It looks something like this.

What is your profession?

- Programmer
- Lawyer
- Doctor
- Athlete

User makes a selection.

How long have you been in this profession?

- 1 Year
- 2 Years
- 10 Years

--

- Doctors with 1 years experience earn 50,000 USD for example.
- Doctors with 2 years experience earn 70,000 USD for example.
- Doctors with 10 years experience earn 100,000 USD for example.

Depending on their answer to the second question I need to somehow dynamically insert this data linked to their first option into the response form.

I have over 300 different variable responses so I don't want to manually create 300 different response forms.

I also want to be able to easily change the values (USD amount) associated with the questions so the output is dynamic.

If you know of any out of the box solutions for doing this, even if it is not using the Gravity Froms plugin I would really appreciate that info.

Any direction or guidance you have on implementing this solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for Gravity Forms conditional shortcode. Here's an example:

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{Profession:2}" condition="is" value="Programmer"]
Content you would like to conditionally display for programmers.
[/gravityforms]
```

More details here: https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-conditional-shortcode/